# Questionning of the resolution of the Tori

Tags: spectral-theory

In the book Eigenvalues in Riemannian Geometry of Isaac Chavel page $28$, I have some questions related to the resolution of the spectrum of the tori.

> The lattice acts on $\mathbb{R}^n$ by $$\gamma(x)=x+\gamma$$ for $x
>  \in \mathbb{R}^n$, $\gamma \in \Gamma$; the action is properly
>   discontinuous, and determines the Riemann covering $p : \mathbb{R}^n
>  \to \mathbb{R}^n/\Gamma.$

1. When it says "the action determines the Riemannian Covering $p : \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^n/\Gamma$", does it means $p(x)= x + \Gamma = \{\gamma(x) : \gamma \in \Gamma\}$?
2. Does $\mathbb{R}^n/\Gamma$ is a Riemann manifold? If so, why?
3. $p$ is a Riemannian covering if it is differentiable covering and local isometry. Could anyone be able to prove that part?

Comment: How exactly is $\Gamma$ defined here?

Comment: The Resolution of the Tori sounds like the title of an awesome movie.